# Is there a way to set chrome options when using the seleniumrequest module?

Tags: selenium, request, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

My goal is it to make a request by using the seleniumrequest module. This is working fine. But now I often get captchas that are harder than the normal ones. So I assume the site is able to detect that I use selenium. So the next step would be that I change the Chrome Options and disable the "attribute" that I am using an automated software. I know how to do it for selenium alone, but it seems that seleniumrequest does not support that. Can somebody confirm this or can tell me what I did wrong.

````
from seleniumrequests import Chrome

webdriver = Chrome()

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

option.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe",options=option)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
```

Would be the options for switching off automated software.

Also ChromeOptions is depreciated use Options instead.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
option = Options()
```

Comment: No problem checkmark my answer if it helped.